# Не сохраняется перевод строки в textarea

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript, textarea

Хэллоу,

в textarea вводится какой-то текст. Рядом кнопка с js-функцией, при нажатии на которую текст обрабатывается и возвращается в textarea. Проблема в том, что текст возвращается без переводов строк. Как сохранить переводы строк?

Например, такая функция. Все работает, но результат возвращается одной сплошной строкой.

```
function addcomma(comma) {
    var str = document.getElementById('comma').value.replace('\r', '');
    var result = str.split('\n');
    var i = 0;
    while (i < result.length) {
        document.getElementById('comma').value = result[i] + ',';
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById('comma').value = result.join(',\n');` не катит?

Comment: катит, спасибо :)

Comment: вот так точнее:
    document.getElementById('comma').value = result.join(',\n');

Comment: Да, точно).

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = document.getElementById('comma').value.replace('\r', '');
var result = str.split('\n');
```

и тут невидно в чем проблема? Сначала косишь в строке все **r** а потом хочешь их **split** как-то нелогично.